# Scrolling with trackpad/mouse in screen on OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, gnu-screen, scrolling

I use screen command on Terminal on OS X.

When I want to scroll up I change the mode to Copy Mode by pressing Ctrl A Esc. Then I use my trackpad to scroll up/down.

It works.

However, sometimes (probably after I press some kind of hot key while I frantically try to copy and paste things), the scrolling with trackpad/mouse doesn't work. Vim hot keys such as j and k still works. It's only the trackpad/mouse that stops working. What it does instead is it immediately quits copy mode and scroll up the history of commands I used.

I need to know what is causing this issue and how to fix it without re opening the terminal.

Comment: run `tput rmcup && tput reset`

Comment: I wanna try if that solves the problem but before you commented I re-opend the terminal to fix it. Since I don't know how to reproduce this issue but happens quite a few times a week, I will try your solution when it happens to me again.

Comment: Nope, that does not work. It "looks" like it does the same thing as "clear"